# formControlName not allowing value

Tags: angular, forms, formgroups

I use formControlName but I also need a value (data.name) for my loop.
But I get an empty input because formControlName doesn´t let me set a value.

html:

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <table>
        <tr *ngFor="let data of readData">
            <td>
                <input type="text" formControlName="name" [value]="data.name">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

component:

```
myForm = new FormGroup ({
  'name': new FormControl(''),
});
```

Comment: I think it seems that you would first of all need a formarray, not only a single formcontrol.

Comment: futhermore, you should **not** use `[value]`. Give value to the FormControl

Answer (score 0):

Remove the "[value]="data.name". The formControl handle the value.

When you create a formControl in formGroup, don't need use ''. Remove it from the name.

```
myForm = new FormGroup ({
  name: new FormControl(''),
});
```

Comment: but how do I set data.name as a value for my inputs?

Comment: With setValue in ts. For example: this.myForm.controls.name.setValue(data.name);

Comment: you need to modify your input data in form of formControl and update myForm like 
    this.thisIsMyForm = this.fb.group({
        formData: this.fb.array([])
    });

Answer (score 0):

Modify your input data and form declaration this way...

```
myForm: FormGroup; // form declaration

// set input data in below format
readData: any[] = [
{name: {formControlName: 'name', name: 'abc', id: 1, disabled: false}}, 
{name: {formControlName: 'name', name: 'xyz', id: 2, disabled: false}},
{name: {formControlName: 'name', name: 'cat', id: 4, disabled: false}}];

// initialize formcontrol name
this.myForm = this.fb.group({
  formData: this.fb.array([])
});

// most critial part could be to setup form group array.
   setupMyForm() {
     const myFA = this.myForm.get('formData') as FormArray;
     this.readData.forEach((data) => {
     const formObject = Object.keys(data).reduce((acc, el) => {
     const { formControlName, disabled } = data[el];
     acc[formControlName] =[{value: data[el].name, disabled}];
     return acc;
     }, {});
     myFA.push(this.fb.group(formObject));
   });
 }
```

// html

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <table formArrayName="formData">
    <tr *ngFor="let data of readData; let i = index" [formGroupName]="i">
      <td>
        <input type="text" placeholder="enter name" formControlName="name" [value]="data"/>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
 <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

check stackblitz example might help you..
[stackblitz working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-button-cyhmrc?file=src/app/app.component.html)